# Intel GPU hangs

Tags: 18.04, intel, gpu-driver

Recently, from around the second half of February, I've experienced freezing on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. The screen would freeze and I can't do anything for a couple of seconds, sometimes it's more severe with flickering, then it goes back to normal, without having to restart.

I've ran `dmesg` after the incidents and got something like this:

```
[20473.312230] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting chip after gpu hang
```

First I've only experienced this in Firefox, when it loads the page but later it reared its head up in other GTK applications, too. A few days ago, I've disabled `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` in the about:config section in Firefox, which I've turned on to prevent screen tearing with video playback, and that, in fact worked, but now it was triggered again.

Is my GPU failing (it's a 2011 i3)? or it's just some regression in the kernel drivers? I've found bug reports on launchpad and other places, but they seem old.

Edit: the kernel I've using is `4.15.0-46-generic`.